# Setting width relatively to the size of the grandparent div

Tags: css

I have the structure that currently looks approximately like the snippet below; how can I make div2 to take the width 50% of its grandparent div, rather than 50% of its immediate parent?

```html
<div id="grandParent" style="width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; background-color: yellow; border-color: yellow">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 100px; background-color: aqua">
    div1
  </div>
  <div id="parent" style="width: 100%; background-color: green">
    parent<br>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 50%; background-color: fuchsia; margin: 0 auto;">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do some maths. The width of the parent is `P - 100px` and you need to have `P/2` so if you do `X/2 + 50px` where `X = P - 100px` you will have `P/2`. Also better use `flex-grow:1` instead of `width:100%` to avoid the shrink effect and have the first div always at `100px`

```js
console.log($('#div2').width())
console.log($('#grandParent').width())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grandParent" style=" display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; background-color: yellow; border-color: yellow">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 100px; background-color: aqua">
    div1
  </div>
  <div id="parent" style="flex-grow:1; background-color: green">
    parent<br>
    <div id="div2" style="width: calc(50% + 50px); background-color: fuchsia; margin: 0 auto;">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can consider the use of CSS variable to make this easier:

```js
console.log($('#div2').width())
console.log($('#grandParent').width())
```

```css
:root {
 --w:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grandParent" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; background-color: yellow; border-color: yellow">
  <div id="div1" style="width: var(--w); background-color: aqua">
    div1
  </div>
  <div id="parent" style="flex-grow:1;background-color: green">
    parent<br>
    <div id="div2" style="width: calc(50% + var(--w)/2); background-color: fuchsia; margin: 0 auto;">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say that this is a bad coding style as it requires the child control to know too much about the whole site structure.

Comment: @user626528 it depends on your *whole* site. I am consider only your restricted example and you can optimize this using CSS variable so the child doesn't really need to know a lot (check the update)